# Android swipe between fragments

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, swipe

In my Android APP I have this ListView where I wish that each item is divided in two parts and it could be swiped. I wonder what should be the best way of doing that since the SlidingDrawer is now deprecated (and is not swippable). I need it to be an easy way to implement and few stress to mobile processor.

The content would be different in each item so I need to be able to access the TextViews inside them.

This is the example I wish to the item od the ListView:
[image]

The user could Swipe between both fragments and check its contents.

Any idea, advice or tutorial on this matter? Thank you very much for your attention

Comment: have you solved this problem ??

Answer (score 2):

Use a `ViewPager`. Really easy to use, just extend a `FragmentPagerAdapter` to create the fragments to swipe between.

Comment: This may seem a basic question, but therefore how can I access the content inside them by id? If I create two classes for each fragment, each one has inflated its own xml layout, from the ListView how can I access these elements from those layouts in order to set them?

Comment: I might be wrong about this one, but I think the fragments are just children of the `ViewPager` object.